# Does jQuery traverse the DOM everytime we use $() to access the same element?

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal

After clicking the button, does jQuery traverse the DOM from the root again or is the child element cached? Will doing something like `var childElement = $('.child')` always make it possible to access the child element directly? Is saving a jQuery object in a variable practiced by developers?

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.child').append('Text. ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Add text</button>

<div class="parent5">
  <div class="parent4">
    <div class="parent3">
      <div class="parent2">
        <div class="parent1">
          <div class="child">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes you should cache the element. Many prepend the jQuery variable with a $, as in `const $childElements = $('.child')` - I write childElements plural, because jQuery will take anything with class child. If there is only ONE child, use ID to document that

Comment: Don’t forget that you can chain most method calls: `$(".child").append("Text. ").fadeIn(300).on("click", console.log).wrap("<div>");` etc.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly if it _"traverses the DOM"_ every time. Some lookups such as by `id` or `class` may be indexed by the browser but this would be implementation specific and nothing to do with jQuery. The general advice given above is best practice though